# how can I add tr aways in first row

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
 <table class="table" id="mytable">
     <tr>

         <th>FIRST NAME</th>
         <th>LAST NAME</th>
         <th>ADDRESS</th>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

how can I append my tr dynamically always in the first row?

I tried this code

```
 $('#mytable tbody tr:last').prependTo('<tr><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td></tr>');
```

it's not working.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like below

```
 $('#mytable tbody tr:first').after('<tr><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td></tr>');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7149wg5x/4/)**

Comment: it add before my header

Comment: is your header is first `tr` inside `tbody` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend(not `prependTo()` since you want to append the right hand element to left) to the `tbody`

```
$('#mytable tbody').prepend('<tr><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td></tr>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7149wg5x/)

Your script is trying to prepend the `tr` to the last row which is not valid

Answer (score 0):

```
just remove tr:last from  $('#mytable tbody tr:last') and use prepend instead

 $('#mytable tbody').prepend('<tr><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td>   </tr>');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruapce/j2st3pzf/)

Answer (score 0):

You have no `tbody` in your HTML, and you need to use `prepend()` rather than `prependTo()`:

HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>FIRST NAME</th>
            <th>LAST NAME</th>
            <th>ADDRESS</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#mytable tbody').prepend('<tr><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td><td>somecontents</td></tr>');
```